# Automatically reclassify small SpatialPolygons inserted into large SpatialPolygons using R

Tags: r, k-means, spatial, raster, r-sp

I would like to assign small polygons nested in larger polygons the same values as those of larger polygons. 
In figure 1 you can see the small polygons in `raster` format:

[image: Raster with small polygons within larger polygons]

and in figure 2 in `SpatialPolygons` as individual polygons:
[image: Disaggregated polygons]

These polygons are results of sorting by k-means, generating raster, and using the `rasterFromXYZ` function (code below):

```
mydata.26.raster <- rasterFromXYZ(as.data.frame(mydata.26.coord[,c("x", "y",       "cls_26.cluster")]),res=5, crs=crs)
```

and then `rasterToPolygons` function I was able to separate the polygons (code below):

```
zona.26.pol<- rasterToPolygons(zona.26.raster$cls_26.cluster,dissolve=TRUE)
zona.26.pol <- disaggregate(zona.26.pol)
```

Here's [zona.26.pol](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj_3CRzoeUoIh7VOiD11PrixCG2CKg?e=5JxnHW) if you want to help It is in .shp format.

And manually I reclassified the polygons and finally added them using the same classes.
After manually assigning the values by me, the result that I would like to achieve automatically (creating rules) is in figure 3:

[image: Reclassified and aggregated final image]

Every help is welcome!

Comment: Can you share ```zona.26.pol``` (result from ```disaggregate```) to test an answer?

Comment: @ThetaFC I edited the question and I put a link to the file in .shp format

If you prefer another format or more files, please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, still need the ```.prj``` file. Or you could share what the projection is.  Looks like a UTM coordinate system.

Comment: @ThetaFC  I updated the file and now it is projecting: + proj = utm + zone = 22 + south + datum = WGS84 + units = m + no_defs + ellps = WGS84 + towgs84 = 0,0,0

I opened in QGis and everything was working, I hope now you can operate.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the small nested polygons based on their size alone and then remove the holes left in the larger, remaining polygons.  This works for your example but may fail if you have larger nested polygons you are wanting to remove.  In that case, we would have to figure out how to identify the geometries that are 'nested'

```
library(sf)
library(units)
library(nngeo)
min_polygon_area  <- 10000 #set minimum size of a nested polygon you would like to remove
units(min_polygon_area) <- as_units('m^2') #as defined below by st_area
zona.26.pol <- st_read(file.path(workDir, 'zona.26.pol.shp'))
st_crs(zona.26.pol) <-  '+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' #define crs
zona.26.pol$area <- st_area(zona.26.pol)
zona.26.pol$area #note area is in m^2
plot(zona.26.pol[,'cls_26_']) #as-is plot
```

[image]

```
zona.26.pol <- zona.26.pol[zona.26.pol$area>min_polygon_area, ]
plot(zona.26.pol[,'cls_26_']) #small polygons removed; holes remaining
```

[image]

```
zona.26.pol_no_holes <- st_remove_holes(zona.26.pol)
plot(zona.26.pol_no_holes[,'cls_26_']) #holes removed
```

[image]
Note that I used the `sf` package to read-in the shapefile, in order to utilize the `st_remove_holes` function from the `nngeo` package, but I typically use `raster` and `sp` packages.